# Manually insert records into SQL Server 2008 change tracking tables?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I want to enable SQL Server 2008's Change Tracking on some of my tables.  I also have some existing historical data that we were tracking another way that we would want to combine with the change tables.  Is there a way to manually insert data into the change tables so that I can include this historical data with new change data?

Comment: The short answer is no: the documentation [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179932.aspx) that system tables including CDC tables should not be modified in any way.

Comment: Depending on how your current change tracking method was constructed you could probably "replay" it somehow with change tracking enabled to allow SQL Server to recreate the structure itself.